# PowerShell cut string in half

Tags: regex, powershell, substring, backtracking, backreference

I have lines that consist of identical halves from which I want to remove one half; e.g, `'AbcAbc'` should become `'Abc'`.

The data always looks like:

```
10.22.20.106/tcp/8010.22.20.106/tcp/80
10.22.20.46/tcp/44310.22.20.46/tcp/443
10.22.20.90/tcp/44310.22.20.90/tcp/443
10.22.20.90/tcp/8010.22.20.90/tcp/80
10.22.20.89/tcp/44310.22.20.89/tcp/443
10.22.20.89/tcp/8010.22.20.89/tcp/80
10.22.20.29/tcp/44310.22.20.29/tcp/443
10.22.20.29/tcp/8010.22.20.29/tcp/80
10.22.20.122/tcp/44310.22.20.122/tcp/443
10.22.20.123/tcp/44310.22.20.123/tcp/443
10.22.20.79/tcp/44310.22.20.79/tcp/443
10.22.20.79/tcp/8010.22.20.79/tcp/80
10.22.20.78/tcp/44310.22.20.78/tcp/443
10.22.20.78/tcp/8010.22.20.78/tcp/80
10.22.20.74/tcp/44310.22.20.74/tcp/443
10.22.20.74/tcp/8010.22.20.74/tcp/80
10.22.20.22/tcp/44310.22.20.22/tcp/443
10.22.20.22/tcp/8010.22.20.22/tcp/80
10.22.20.99/tcp/44310.22.20.99/tcp/443
10.22.20.99/tcp/8010.22.20.99/tcp/80
10.22.20.54/tcp/44310.22.20.54/tcp/443
10.22.20.54/tcp/8010.22.20.54/tcp/80
```

I count the number of characters in the string and then halve it, but not sure how to use the calculated (halved) number of characters to cut the original string.

```
$vip_ip = $vip_line.("Virtual IP Address/Protocol/Port")
$half_string = $vip_ip.length /2
```

**$vip_ip.length
44**

**$half_string
22**

```
$vip_cut = $vip_ip.(0,-$halfstring)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to gather the information that you would need for the string method `"".SubString()`

In your case you just need something like this:

```
$vip_ip.substring(0,$halfstring)
```

From the start of the string and go halfway. Could also start from halfway to the end as well since the answer is the same. `SubString()` supports both overloads.

```
$vip_ip.substring($halfstring)
```

Answer (score 3):

**[Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55120893/45375) is the way to go**, but just to present a [*regex*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions)-based alternative with 
`-replace`, mostly as an interesting *experiment*:

Note: While this solution is concise, it's obscure and 2-3 times slower in my tests than the `.Substring()`-based approach.

```
# Extract one half of the input string consisting of identical halves.
PS> '10.22.20.54/tcp/44310.22.20.54/tcp/443' -replace '^(.+)\1$', '$1'
10.22.20.54/tcp/443
```

- Regex subexpression `^(.+)` matches one or more (`+`) (non-newline) characters (`.`) at the start (`^`) of the string and captures them `(...)` in a *capture group*.
- `\1$` matches a *backreference* (`\1`), which refers to what the (1st and only) capture group matched, at the end of the string (`$`).
  In effect, the whole regex will only match if the input consists of identical halves.
- `$1` as the `-regex` replacement operand then returns what the (1st and only) capture group matched, which is the input string's first half.

Note that such a regex is inefficient, because it requires a lot of *backtracking*, given that the halfway point isn't known in advance.
Using a *non-greedy* modifier (`+?` instead of `+`) works too in this case, but in practice seems to make no difference in terms of performance (presumably, use of `.+?` then requires an equal number of "*forward* tracking" attempts).